# React Bundle Size increases in Create React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, bundle, create-react-app

After analyzing app in source-map-explorer 
61.5% is been consumed by [no source]
what is this no source in [No Source] 3.56 MB 61.5% in 0.chunk.js bundle?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's because CRA generates source maps in default, in your package.json modify your build command like this :
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"

Comment: by doing this I unable to access source-map-explorer and bundle size just decreased by 44b